# Rails SQL: Creating a query dynamically

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to create a dynamic query based on User inputs

```
if a
  conditions << ["fname like (?)"]
  sql_params <<  "abc"
end
if b
  conditions << ["lname like (?)"]  
  sql_params <<  "def"  
end
if c
  cconditions << ["middle like (?)"]  
  sql_params <<  "xyz"   
end

results = Model.where(conditions.join(' AND '), sql_params)
```

While the conditions get in correct syntax, the sql_params are listed as an array. This forms the below query

```
Model.where("fname like (?) AND lname like (?) AND middle like (?)", ["abc","def","xyz"])
```

while what I need is

```
Model.where("fname like (?) AND lname like (?) AND middle like (?)", "abc","def","xyz")
```

I tried several map/join etc options on the sql_params array but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `sql_params` with `*` (known as [splat operator](https://devblast.com/b/ruby-splat-operator)) i.e.

```
results = Model.where(conditions.join(' AND '), *sql_params)
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks so much. I spent so much time on this.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you need to produce exactly this?

```
Model.where("fname like (?) AND lname like (?) AND middle like (?)", "abc","def","xyz")
```

Something of the form:

```
Model.where('expr1 AND expr2 AND expr3')
```

is equivalent to:

```
Model.where('expr1').where('expr2').where('expr3')
```

so why not build the query piece by piece rather than messing around with strings? Something like this:

```
query = Model.all
query = query.where('fname  like ?', 'abc') if a
query = query.where('lname  like ?', 'def') if b
query = query.where('middle like ?', 'xyz') if c
```

will give you the same result.